Pipewire not detecting Microphone, plugged in but static comes out of internal microphone recording
I am on an Alienware M16 running Arch Linux and Pipewire is installed and there are 2 controllers that are available, one controlled by the Nvidia Graphics card and one controlled by the AMD audio controller. Connecting an external headset by cable to headphone jack makes the microphone work but when external headset is not connected, the internal microphone only records static noise and does not react whatsoever to any external stimuli.
pactl list cards
outputs
Card #41
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
        Driver: alsa
        Owner Module: n/a
        Properties:
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "0"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xc1000000 irq 114"
                api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                device.description = "HDA NVidia"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
                device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
                device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
                device.plugged.usec = "11825145"
                device.product.id = "0x22bc"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
                device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                media.class = "Audio/Device"
                factory.id = "14"
                client.id = "40"
                object.id = "41"
                object.serial = "41"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xc1000000 irq 114"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU a5 HDMI/DP"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10de00a5,10280bfe,00100100"
                alsa.id = "NVidia"
                device.string = "0"
        Profiles:
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
        Active Profile: pro-audio
        Ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "0"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "1"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "2"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "3"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #42
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.6
        Driver: alsa
        Owner Module: n/a
        Properties:
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "1"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc17c0000 irq 115"
                api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:09:00.6"
                device.description = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
                device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.6"
                device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
                device.plugged.usec = "12540671"
                device.product.id = "0x15e3"
                device.product.name = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.6/sound/card1"
                device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                media.class = "Audio/Device"
                factory.id = "14"
                client.id = "40"
                object.id = "42"
                object.serial = "42"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc17c0000 irq 115"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3254"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0295,10280bfe,00100002"
                alsa.id = "Generic"
                device.string = "1"
        Profiles:
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
                input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
                pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 2, priority: 1, available: yes)
        Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        Ports:
                analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "mic"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                                card.profile.port = "0"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (type: Headset, priority: 8800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, availability unknown)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "headset"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                                card.profile.port = "1"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "speaker"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                                card.profile.port = "2"
                        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo

The device Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo in pavucontrol 'Input Devices' tab has the options of 'Headset Microphone' and 'Microphone' available. The same device in 'Configuration' tab has the options 'Analog Stereo Input', 'Analog Stereo Output', 'Analog Stereo Input', 'Pro Audio', and 'Off'.
sudo dmesg | grep -E 'audio|jack|pipewire|pulse|alsa'
outputs
[   11.751401] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   11.751560] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
[   11.753103] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.6: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
[   11.836630] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3254: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   11.836633] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.836635] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.836637] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.836638] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[   11.836639] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[   11.836640] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1b

wpctl status
outputs
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, cookie:355324114]
 └─ Clients:
        31. kwin_wayland                        [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1171]
        32. WirePlumber                         [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1241]
        40. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1241]
       135. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1179]
       136. pipewire                            [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1742]
       137. KMix                                [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1726]
       138. libcanberra                         [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1432]
       139. plasmashell                         [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1432]
       140. Plasma PA                           [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:1432]
       149. Dolphin                             [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:6878]
       166. Google Chrome input                 [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:473]
       226. audacity.bin                        [0.3.83, UserName@Computer, pid:2]
       253. Plasma PA                           [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:19329]
       271. ZOOM VoiceEngine                    [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:5]
       340. qpwgraph                            [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:15451]
       574. wpctl                               [1.0.7, UserName@Computer, pid:23910]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      41. HDA NVidia                          [alsa]
 │      42. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller  [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      46. HDA NVidia Pro                      [vol: 1.00]
 │      47. HDA NVidia Pro 7                    [vol: 1.00]
 │      48. HDA NVidia Pro 8                    [vol: 1.00]
 │      49. HDA NVidia Pro 9                    [vol: 1.00]
 │  *  298. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *  297. Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Filters:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      52. Integrated_Webcam_FHD               [v4l2]
 │      53. Integrated_Webcam_FHD               [v4l2]
 │      54. Integrated_Webcam_FHD               [v4l2]
 │      55. Integrated_Webcam_FHD               [v4l2]
 │      59. Integrated_Webcam_FHD: Integrat     [libcamera]
 │      60. Integrated_Webcam_FHD: Integrat     [libcamera]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   61. Integrated_Webcam_FHD (V4L2)       
 │      63. Integrated_Webcam_FHD (V4L2)       
 │  
 ├─ Filters:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Devices:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_input.pci-0000_09_00.6.pro-input-0

lsof /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig
brought back nothing.
sudo ps aux | grep -E 'alsa|pulse|jack|pipewire'
brought back
UserName      1226  0.5  0.3 296744 117160 ?       S<sl 12:47   1:19 /usr/bin/pipewire
UserName      1742  0.3  1.1 488224 380748 ?       S<sl 12:47   0:50 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
UserName      8572  0.0  0.8 2496804 258780 ?      Ssl  13:40   0:03 /usr/bin/dolphin --new-window --select admin:/etc/pipewire/
UserName     11948  0.0  0.7 1946940 243756 ?      Ssl  14:07   0:03 /usr/bin/kate -b /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf
UserName     19329  0.0  0.8 2904680 257088 ?      Ssl  15:26   0:04 systemsettings kcm_pulseaudio
UserName     25507  0.0  0.0   6612  4084 pts/3    S+   17:09   0:00 grep --color=auto -E alsa|pulse|jack|pipewire

This is what the qpwgraph looks like:
qpwgraph setup
I tried reinstalling Pipewire and I also tried messing around with qpwgraph and it seemed like the audio capture was not working, but it did connect to inputs from apps such as Audacity and Zoom's Voice Engine. I even tried using the command
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.6 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
and nothing seemed to work. I was expecting the card to be set to the right one and the internal microphone would finally work, but it did not. I also tried messing around with alsamixer and boosting all input from the generic audio card and unmuting all bands but that did not work either. Changing the microphone in alsamixer from headset microphone to headphone microphone did not change anything either.
Here is the screenshot from alsamixer in terminal:
alsamixer sound connfiguration having hit F5 showing all devices in audio card Realtek ALC3254

Here is the output for pactl list sources: https://pastebin.com/J4WBDZN3

If there is anything else I have to add then just tell me and I will provide the info asap!
